# Problem with ''\hfill''

Tags: hfill

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,amsthm,mathtools,systeme}

\begin{document}
\noindent Answer using ``T'' for True or ``F'' for False for the given statements:
\begin{enumerate}
\item The differential equation $(x^2+y^2)dx+8xydy=0$ is homogeneous.\hfill (....)
\item  $(D+2)\left[\sin(2x)\right]=2\cos(2x)+2\sin(2x)$.\hfill (....)
\item $\frac{1}{D^2+2D-8}\left[e^{3x}\right]=\frac{1}{7}e^{3x}$.
\item To solve the homogeneous differential equation $(2x-3y)dx+(2y+3x)dy=0$, we take the substitution $y=ux$.
\item The integrating factor $\mu(x)$ of the differential equation $-ydx+xdy=0$, which convert it to an exact differential equation is 
\begin{equation*}
\mu(x)=e^{-2\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{x}dx}.
\end{equation*}
\hfill (....)
 \end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

I like to obtain as shown in this pic

[image]

Comment: Assuming that I understand what you are after from the picture (moving the dots in brackets up to the text, rather than in line with the equation), moving the `\hfill (....)` to before the first `$$` would do it. Other people may have other suggestions about what you are wanting to do, though. Incidentally, using `$$` is discouraged: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69854

Comment: If you want to have (....) at the same baseline as the display formula then you can write `$$ formula \eqno (....)$$`

Comment: Please, [don't use `$$…$$` in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/277964).

Comment: Ok I fiexed my question. Thanks

Comment: (1) use `\exp(...)` here not `e^{...}` the latter is horrible to read. (2) use `equation` and overwrute the eq number via `\tag{...}`.

Comment: Is the intent for `(....)` to be where the students write in T or F? Would you be open to solutions that move where that spot is? (Perhaps immediately before or immediately after the statement number?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For item 5 I'd just use

```
\begin{equation*}
\mu(x)=\exp\biggl(-2\int\frac{1}{x}\,dx\biggr). \tag{...}
\end{equation*}
```

- uses `\exp(...)` instead of the (in this case) unreadable `e^{...}`
- uses `\tag{...}` to give and overwrite the equation number

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks like this:

```
some text \begin(equation*) x*y \end(equation*) \hfill (...)
```

but it should be like this:

```
some text \hfill (...)
\vskip 0pt plus 2pt minus 0pt \relax
\begin(equation*) x*y \end(equation*)
```

You can omit the plus n minus m part and finish directly with the \relax. It's just, that you have seen it, if you ever encounter it. I just like to put vskips at such places.

If you use LaTeX, you have to think in boxes. Your text before the equation is a box, the whole line. Then, after that, your formula is in a box, that takes the full line width. After that, you have a new line that is filled with white space until the brackets with the three dots. That's, why your example gives you that output. My explanation might not be 100% technically correct, but helps you understanding the concepts of LaTeX.